# Avoid applying style for an empty title element in a DITA file

Tags: xml, xslt, openxml, dita, dita-ot

I have a certain dita file with an empty title tag. It looks something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE topic PUBLIC "-//OASIS/DTD DITA topic//EN" "topic.dtd">
<topic id="some_topic_id">
<title></title>
    <body>
      <p> This is a paragraph </p>
    </body>
</topic>
```

I will be using the DitaOT plugin to generate a word output from the dita file
Now, my DitaOT plugin reads this dita file and applies style to the empty title tag.
Is there any way to avoid styling getting applied to the empty title tag? How should I modify the xsl document in such a way that the styling is skipped when title tag is empty?

Comment: In DITA authoring, topic/title is most important part. If topic has no body element but has title element, it is assumed as valid DITA topic. What is your intention to make title content empty?

Comment: For those familiar with XSLT but less familiar with the DitaOT framework, it might be helpful to post the XSLT or point to the base doc, so that we can see what templates, modes, etc. are applied and either prototype a solution or make suggestions. Ideally, you could target the empty `title` elements and either remove in a pre-rendering transform or match on those `title` specifically and ensure that normal rendering templates do not match and render default content.